# How to specify pod to node affinity in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

How can I configure a specific pod to run on a multi-node kubernetes cluster so that it would restrict the containers of the POD to a subset of the nodes.

E.g. let's say I have A, B, C three nodes running mu kubernetes cluster.

How to limit a Pod to run its containers only on A & B, and not on C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add label to nodes that you want to run pod on and add nodeSelector to pod configuration. The process is described here:

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/node-selection/

So basically you want to

```
kubectl label nodes A node_type=foo
kubectl label nodes B node_type=foo
```

And you want to have this nodeSelector in your pod spec:

```
nodeSelector:
    node_type: foo
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you need to add label to nodes. You can refer to Nebril's answer of how to add label.

Then I recommend you to use the ***node affinity*** feature to constrain pods to nodes with particular labels. Here is an example.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: with-node-affinity
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: node_type
            operator: In
            values:
            - foo
  containers:
  - name: with-node-affinity
    image: gcr.io/google_containers/pause:2.0
```

Compared to ***nodeSelector***, the affinity/anti-affinity feature greatly expands the types of constraints you can express.

For more detailed information about ***node affinity***, you can refer to the following link: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/

Comment: I ma looking for a way to auto lable a node being added to a pool or to use the node `name` in matchExpressions.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by auto label? Also, is that related to the original question? Maybe posting a separate question may help.

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to post a comment to previous replies but I upvoted the answer that is complete.
**nodeSelector is not strictly enforced** and relying on it may cause some grief including Master getting overwhelmed with requests as well as IOs from pods scheduled on Master. At the time the answer was provided it may still have been the only option but in the later versions that is not so.

Definitely use **nodeAffinity** or **nodeAntiAffinity** with requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution or preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution

For more expressive filters for scheduling peruse: [Assigning pods to nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#taints-and-tolerations-beta-feature)